# Compiler calculating mistake

Tags: c++, mingw, pow

I have this big homework assignment and I got unexpected results, I traced it down to the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cout << (int)((7163 / (int) pow (10, 4 - i - 1))) % 10;
```

to which 7263 appears on the screen, instead of 7163! This does not happen to every 4 digit number and it leaves me confused, is there something wrong with my logic or the compiler's gone nuts. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Post the remaining code, this way it's easier to understand your problem. Also if you could post some inputs and the expected result it would help

Comment: I don't think there's more to my problem, I made a separate program and placed these two lines in the main, it still outputs 7263, the expected result would be the same number between the two (int)-s.

Comment: For the given example, what result were you expecting besides `7263`?

Comment: I was expecting 7163

Comment: When I run your code, as shown, with no other code around it, I get `7163`. Are you sure what you show above is what you ran to get `7263`? What OS and what compiler are you using?

Comment: Absolutely, when I run it on other numbers it works fine, I have no idea what's causing this, my guess is some kind of compiler mishap and I sure hope the guys that's going to be checking this doesn't have the same one as I do. Using Windows 7 Prof and MinGW

Comment: When I run it with 7163 it also works fine, although I am on a different system and different compiler. What compiler are you using under MinGW? MinGW isn't a compiler. That would be a fairly fundamental and unlikely bug. Double check your code indeed has 7163.

Comment: Weird. I haven't tried duplicating this, but it looks like it is rounding 71.63 to 72 (and then outputting 2 after the `% 10`). Does a similar error happen with other numbers that might round (e.g., does 6263 result in 6363)?

Comment: http://s14.postimg.org/65zn7adb5/baffled.png   here's a link

Comment: Yup, 6263 results in 6363

Comment: So integer divide with your compiler is rounding rather than truncating.

Comment: Looks like you may have a buggy compiler. Your posted code ran as expected for me.

Comment: I think my compiler is GDB, that's what it says when I try to debug atleast

Comment: GDB isn't a compiler. It's a debugger. What command did you type in to compile? And as a comparison, try `cout << (int)(floor(7163 / pow(10, 4 - i - 1))) % 10`, which should force the behavior you expect. Or more interesting, try: `cout << ((int)(7163 / pow(10, 4 - i - 1))) % 10`.

Comment: I'm not on linux I just push the button to compile :D Ok hold on, is g++ a compiler?

Comment: Yes, g++. Which is also what I'm using on Linux. Now try: `g++ --version` and tell us what version it is.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the trick, thank you very much :)

Comment: I'd still be interested in knowing the version of your g++, and whether my second suggestion would work. :) The one I have is 4.7.2 dated 2012/09/21.

Comment: I believe g++ --version is a code for the linux console, I'm not on linux, any other way I can tell my compiler version? And yes, your code worked.

Comment: I don't know what IDE you're using then. You must have an IDE.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I use codeblocks

Comment: You'd have to enter `g++ --version` at a MinGW command prompt. So it appears, though, that your compiler is promoting numerator 7163 to a `float` even though it's casting the denominator to an `int`. Maybe you have an older compiler version that has since been fixed.

Comment: One way to get the GCC compiler version is to add these lines to your program: `#define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)` and `cout << "GCC Version: " << GCC_VERSION <<  "\n\n";`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my version is 4.9.2

Comment: I don't repro this with MinGW 4.9.2-3 from TDM.  You might want to let people know exactly where you got the compiler (or IDE if it was packaged with it). Also, you might want to post a complete program that repros the problem - `#includes` and everything (it looks like it should be less than 20 lines).  Also any build logs that include the compiler command used to build the program. Something weird is going on - either a *very* fundamental bug in a very specific compiler build or there's some key information missing from what you have posted in your question.

Comment: If OP is using g++-4.9.2, he is **not** using MinGW; compilers from TDM are **not** MinGW; compilers from mingw-w64 are **not** MinGW. The *registered trademark* "MinGW" is owned by MinGW.org, who have yet to release an official MinGW GCC-4.9.2, because building it has proven to be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not with the compiler, but rather with the standard library implementation of the `pow` function.

But it is really not advisable to use `(int)(pow(n, k))` to compute *n*<sup>*k*</sup> with two integers.

`pow` is not guaranteed to produce an exact answer; it may be out by a very small amount. (Actually, its accuracy is not guaranteed at all, but most implementations will try to not be wrong by more than the value of the low order bit of the result.) Since casting to `(int)` *truncates* rather than rounds, even a tiny error can result in the result being off by 1. And in this case, if the result of `pow(10,2)` ends up being 99.999999999999, then converting it to an int will make it 99, and 7163/99 is 72.

So if you insist on using `pow`, you need to ensure that the result is *rounded* rather than truncated (see the `round` standard library function). But it would be better to stick to integer arithmetic. For example:

```
for (int i = 1000; i > 0; i /= 10)
  std::cout << 7163 / i % 10;
```

Comment: It's amazing how often and easily floating point arithmetic can bite you in the ass - even the simplest uses.  One thing I'm still left wondering about is why the OP would get different results than everyone else testing on MinGW. I would have thought it would use the `pow()` implementation in `msvcrt.dll` so there would be little or no problem reproducing the problem. But maybe I'm wrong and some or all MinGW distros have a custom `pow()` implementation? Maybe I'll look into that tonight.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I have no windows environment to test with, so I can only speculate. I would have thought it would use `msvcrt.dll`, but perhaps OP's environment uses an alternate library. Regardless, it is good to learn early about the dangers of float->int truncation; SO is full of similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I understand is that the result at i=1 yields a "2" when you would expect a "1".

7163 / (10^2) = 71.63... so it is pretty feasible to assume you are simply treading on a rounding error. How the value calculations are being done will depend on your environment, which you haven't specified, however it seems apparent that the assumptions your code makes about order of operations and data types are incorrect.

A heavy handed approach would be to more strictly cast your types and define your order of operations, leaving nothing to chance:

```
cout << ((int) (((int) 7163) / ((int) pow (10, 4 - i - 1)))) % 10;
```

Even still, you may need to incorporate a math library and perform a truncate operation on your division result if the environment insists on providing a floating point result.

Comment: All those casts don't help at all. You need to round, not truncate, the result of pow. Or better yet, use integer arithmetic instead.